# How to store a queue of people in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, queue

I am building a Hospital management system which has a booking/appointment feature. I need to store a queue of people waiting to see the same doctor. How do I implement and store this in mongodb? This queue doesn't need to be FIFO and the order of people in queue has to mutable. Is there any mechanism already built for this? Please help.
I am using express and mongoose for backend.